# Setting up a test Database for jest tests on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am quite new to Testing with jest and was learning to write tests for my code. The current setup is :

```
    //cityService.ts:
import {inject, injectable} from "inversify";
import {NUCLEUS_TYPES} from "../nucleus/NUCLEUS_TYPES";
import {AppLogger} from "../libs/logger";
import {CityReadOnlyDao, CityReadWriteDao} from "../nucleus/daos/cityDao";
import {ICityAttributes} from "../nucleus/interfaces/attributeInterfaces";
import {ICityModel} from "../nucleus/interfaces/modelInterfaces";
import {BaseService} from "../nucleus/services/baseService";
import {escapeRegExp} from "../utils/helper";
import {SortOrder} from "../nucleus/constants/enums";

@injectable()
export class CityService extends BaseService<ICityModel, ICityAttributes>{
    constructor(@inject(NUCLEUS_TYPES.AppLogger) protected appLogger: AppLogger,
                @inject(NUCLEUS_TYPES.ReadOnlyDao.City) protected cityReadOnlyDao: CityReadOnlyDao,
                @inject(NUCLEUS_TYPES.ReadWriteDao.City) protected cityReadWriteDao: CityReadWriteDao){
        super(cityReadOnlyDao, cityReadWriteDao);
    }

    async suggestCity(req) {
        this.appLogger.debug(typeof req.body.query);
        let regQuery = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(req.body.query.trim()), 'i');
        let cities = await this.find({
            condition: {'name': {$regex: regQuery}},
            sortField: 'used',
            sortOrder: SortOrder.DESC,
            count: (req.body.limit ? Number(req.body.limit) : 10),
            start: (req.body.skip ? Number(req.body.skip) : 0)
        });
        return ({state: true, cities});
    }
}
```

And a  sample test is :

```
import { CityService } from "../src/services/cityService";
import container from "../src/libs/ioc";

let cityService = container.get<CityService>(TYPES.Service.City);

test("Testing with full Name", async () => {
        expect.hasAssertions();
        let response = await cityService.suggestCity({
            body: {
                query: 'London'
            }
        });
        expect(response.cities).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([expect.objectContaining({ name: 'London' })]));
    });
```

The test runs and passes without a hitch. Now my doubt was that I am hitting my database with this test. Is there a way to test this without the function calling my database? Perhaps Making a mock database. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how should I proceed with it?

Comment: As you say you'd need to mock your database. One way to do this would be to have your DAO object conform to a particular interface itself. Then in your test class, you inject a MockDAO that conforms to this database. It could just use an array or some other kind of in-memory database (SQLite) and just needs the same particular methods (`find` etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tommy. Can you explain the DAO Object conforming to a particular interface? Do we just define an interface where we connect to this mock Database?

Comment: So you’d define something like a DatabaseInterface that has method such as ‘find’ your DAO would implement this interface, then you could create a TestDAO that also conforms to this interface. Then you just pass your TestDAO in your test class rather than the actual DAO